# Checking part of a kernel transition definition on a $\pi$-system.

Tags: probability-theory

Here's the definition of a transitional kernel:[image]

My doubt is in the next picture. 
[image]
Theorem 1.19, just states that the $\lambda$-system generated by the $\pi$-system $\mathcal{E}$ is equal to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$.

I don't understand why we have $\mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{E})$?

Also, can I assume that sigma algebra associated with $[0,\infty]$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,\infty])$?

Comment: *Hint:* Since ${\cal E}\subset {\cal D}$ we have $\lambda({\cal E})\subset\lambda({\cal D})$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks for the hint. So, we have $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\subset \lambda(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{D}$. How would we be able to prove equality?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I've just noticed $\mathcal{D}\subset \sigma(\mathcal{E})$. Thanks. ;)